# Sequelize dont use the db name in config and try to connect to "postgres"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to connect to a elephantSQL server, but sequelize try to connect to a database with the name "postgres" ignoring the name declared in the config.

Here is the error, note that the database are "postgres":

```
ERROR: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "168.196.104.204", user "bxutatfx", database "postgres", SSL off
```

and the config:

```
module.exports = {
    dialect: "postgres",
    host: "tuffi.db.elephantsql.com",
    username: "bxutatfx",
    password: "dbPassword",
    database: "bxutatfx",
    define: {
        timestamps: true,
        underscored: true,
    },
};
```

and here the connection:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const dbConfig = require('../config/database');

const connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig);

module.exports = connection;
```

If more information is needed just ask, Thanks :)

Comment: you misspelled `uderscored`

Comment: Can you include the code where you create the Sequelize connection?

Comment: done, the connection is there.

Comment: I created a local server and this error dont happen when i connect, must be something with the elaphantsql